# How to change frame of a custom table view cell only for a particular cell in ios objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i am using custom table view cell, if a row is odd then i have to give padding 10 left and right of a cell, otherwise no padding. I had used setFrame in custom table view class as follows. But its giving padding for all cells.I want to give padding only for odd rows. Advance Thanks for any help.

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
        frame.origin.x += 10;
        frame.size.width = frame.size.width - 20;
        [super setFrame:frame];

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an attribute to your custom cell, like a boolean.
Then in setFrame :

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if(self.isOdd) {
        frame.origin.x += 10;
        frame.size.width = frame.size.width - 20;
    }
    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

Then

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [...]
    //check if your cell is odd or not
    if(theCellIsOdd)
        [theCell setIsOdd:YES];
    else
        [theCell setIsOdd:NO];
    [...]
    return theCell;

}
```

Comment: You are awesome. Thanks a lot

Comment: Does this really always work? I've had bad experiences incrementing dimensions on frames for cells in the past, since they are reused; so I tend to set the desired dimensions statically with a #define